# How to simulate power-related events for tests

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I am building an application that monitors the status of a UPS (Uninterruptible power supply, not the freight company) in order to react to the change of state in power.

I use the [PowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus.aspx) class that gives the informations we (% Battery remaining, whether runninig on AC or on battery, if USB connection is available)

For our unit tests, I have my own class that acts like a facade to the PowerStatus class and I mock this class to inject the various events.

What I need is a way to simulate the UPS behavior on our integration system. Is there any way to emulate a UPS either directly with windows or through WMI?

Comment: You might be into hardware solutions here, emulating the UPS protocol with a serial loopback cable or Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

The **apcupsd** project has a wealth of information on the subject of monitoring a UPS. I realize APC is not the entire market here but you can use their line protocol to attempt to emulate a device. The project is open source and may give you a start:

- http://www.apcupsd.org/
- http://www.apcupsd.org/manual/manual.html#apc-smart-protocol